# Making custom meta box required (with error message if not filled in) on Gutenberg

Tags: custom-field, metabox, block-editor, validation, post-editor

```
<input required name="myName" type="text" value="<?php echo $myValue; ?>" class="regular-text">
```

Does not produce an error message if the field is left blank when I attempt to Update.

What else do I need to do in order to tell the user that this field is required in Gutenberg?

Using the Classic Editor plugin it won't even let me update the page. It presents me with a "!" tooltip that says "Please fill out this field." :)

Thanks!

Comment: why does `@myvalue` start with a `@`? Note that this is **much** much easier to do if you're registering a panel or sidebar in Gutenberg via javascript/react, than if you use PHP for everything, there are even frameworks for pre-publish checklists that prevent publishing if requirements aren't met

Comment: Sorry typo on the variable, fixed. So simple to add HTML5 `required` attribute which works in classic editor, but not available in Gutenberg? Is this a "bug" / outstanding update perhaps?

Comment: `required` only works if you're submitting a form and relies on browser behaviour entirely, but the block editor uses the REST API, so you should not expect it to work in Gutenberg. PHP meta-boxes are there for backwards compatibility, they aren't a high priority for new features and aimed at not breaking existing code, rather than supporting new code. You would be far better served by a Gutenberg native UI. You're welcome to try and make it work with a PHP metabox but you'll end up implementing almost all of a native solution and then some to get there, javascript will be unavoidable